# Networking start loading issue

Tags: swift, networking, rx-swift

I'm using the next states to handle my API state

```
enum RequestState<T: Decodable> {
    case loading
    case loaded(T)
    case error(Error)
}
```

and the following code to change these states:

```
let response = request
    .flatMapLatest {
        provider.rx.request($0)
        .map(T.self).map { RequestState.loaded($0) }
        .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error in
            return Driver.just(.error(error))
        })
     .startWith(.loading)
}
```

all works awesome but except one issue. `case loading` works only when all fine with network and request in progress.

**Connection**

Tap - Loading spinner - Response

**No connection**

Tap - network thining delay - No connection response

I would like to start loading on tap always. Maybe use the new state `case startedLoading`. And get this state when a new request pushed to the sequence (ex. after tap refresh button).

Comment: The code you posted will emit `.loading` at the start of every request from this stream. Whatever is wrong with your code isn't here.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, `.loading` is emitted only after the first `request` observable emits a next value, as `startWith` is applied to the inner observable.

Moving `.startWith` to the outer observable will ensure you always get a `.loading` event before any other.

```swift
let response = request
    .flatMapLatest {
        provider.rx.request($0)
        .map(T.self).map { RequestState.loaded($0) }
        .asDriver(onErrorRecover: { error in
            return Driver.just(.error(error))
        })
    }
    .startWith(.loading)
```

Comment: My request `sequence` creates from `Signal.merge(request, refresh.withLatestFrom(request)` initial request and refresh tap request. With your solution `loading` called only once. When I tap the refresh button nothing happens.